# Deforming a circle into closed smooth curve

Tags: complex-analysis, geometric-topology

If we throw a rubber band on to a smooth table it wiggles and takes variegated shapes  before coming to rest. However, the deformed  band
while taking different shapes remains closed and smooth. I am curious to know if  there is mathematically some way, say through some complex transformation, to achieve it. In other words, how can we change the boundary of circle into an arbitrary closed smooth curve. 
 **My vague idea**  Take a variable point $(x,y) $ on the circle and define two functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ so that the point $(u,v)$ traces a requisite curve as $(x,y)$ moves on the circle. I tried a few functions but ended up  obtaining  some nondifferentiable points on the transformed curve.  I will be highly obliged for any responses/hints/suggestions.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem), "In complex analysis, the Riemann mapping theorem states that if $U$ is a non-empty simply connected open subset of the complex number plane $\bf C$ which is not all of $\bf C$, then there exists a biholomorphic mapping $f$ (i.e. a bijective holomorphic mapping whose inverse is also holomorphic) from $U$ onto the open unit disk ${\displaystyle D=\{z\in \mathbf {C} :|z|<1\}.}D=\{z\in \mathbf {C} :|z|<1\}$.

Comment: True and thanks for pointing it out  but I want an algorithmic approach for this particular problem

Comment: One idea is to use mean curvature flow~ then you invert the "flow" to get your process https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve-shortening_flow

Comment: Abother idea is to define an energy functonal between two curves then let one curve "gradient descent" that functional

Comment: Did you notice that there's an "Algorithms" section at the Wikipedia link that I gave?

Comment: If you want an "algorithmic" solution, then you have to explain how is your topological curve is given: An input for an algorithm has to be constructive.  Also, you have to explain what computability model you are working with (since you are dealing with real numbers). You should explain this not in comments, but by editing the post.